# 'both (nouns)' vs 'both the (nouns)'

Tags: grammaticality

> Racial stereotypes, like so
>   many other forms of prejudice (gender, class), have an extraordinary capacity to
>   convey perceptions (and feelings) of the Other which bear little, if any, relationship to
>   external reality. However, these highly distorted images, instead of being recognized
>   for what they are, are understood as real- world entities. So powerfully can stereotypes
>   substitute for reality that the racist can see in both ♦ black and Jew, even when they are
>   directly perceived, qualities the very opposite of those that are being observed.
>
> Source: Racism in Europe by Neil McMaster, Palgrave, 2001

At the black lozenge, why isn't there the indefinite article 'the'? 'black and Jew' are 2 nouns?

Source: p 94, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Answer (score 1):

'The' is the definite article. 'A/an' is the indeifinite.

The author here uses these singular nouns (black and Jew) to refer to both races in general. It is not an atypical construction, I just don't happen to know its formal name. I think it can be fairly equated to him saying (blacks and Jews). Since it is a general reference the definite article is not used.

See

http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-when-not-to-use-the-definite-article/